# Ability to identify customers / orders placed via the REST API

Tags: wordpress, api, email, woocommerce

Is there a function (or at least a plugin) that identifies a customer created through the REST API, and prevents them from sending emails as "account creation confirmation" or "order confirmation"?

Thanks per advance,
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 3.9.1 update of Woocommerce, we have a function to do that :
https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_orderget_created_via/

```
$string = WC_Order::get_created_via( $context );
```